# when i am trying to run a perl file i am getting permission denied error

Tags: 14.04, permissions, perl

```
/usr/local/share/lxr/lxr-2.0.3/scripts$ ls
ANSI-escape.sh    ContextMgr.pm        LCLInterpreter.pm  QuestionAnswer.pm  set-lxr-version.sh  VTescape.pm
configure-lxr.pl  kernel-vars-grab.sh  lighttpd-init      recreatedb.pl      Tagger.pm
/usr/local/share/lxr/lxr-2.0.3/scripts$ sudo ./configure-lxr.pl -vv
sudo: unable to execute ./configure-lxr.pl: Permission denied
```

I have got perl5 installed and it is in `/usr/lib/perl5`, can anyone point where the problem is and how to proceed?

Comment: Please try `ls -la` to see the permission of the file **configure-lxr.pl** and give it executable permission `sudo chmod a+x configure-lxr.pl` where necessary.

Comment: @Zack Titan 2.0.3/scripts$ ls -la
total 148

-rwxrwxrwx 1 ashwanth ashwanth 24593 Feb 24 21:00 configure-lxr.pl

-
it has got 777 permission.

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/local/share/lxr/lxr-2.0.3/scripts$ su perl configure-lxr.pl
```

try this after running this  will be asked for password, enter password and proceed.
if this not works than let me know ok .